# Code Golf Blog - Phase 1 - Raise the idea on the meta site

Tags: discussion, blog-discussion

It might be interesting if [we had a community blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) for our site.

Maybe we could blog about specific exemplary posts here, or about golfing in general, or about exploring some things about our site (like the recent code-trolling invasion), or about current events related to golfing or our site, or about programming challenges, or about any number of things.

But if we want this, we'll have to organize it ourselves, since it's a *community* blog!

The post linked above has a four-step process to create a blog. The first step is to raise the idea on the meta site, which I am doing now. The blog will only work if the community wants a blog. From the same post:

> A community blog needs the involvement of community members.  These blogs don’t exist to be the personal blog of a community member.  They are both for and run by the community.  It needs to be something the community collectively wants and will cultivate.

So, what do you think? Do we want a blog? Would it help out our site?

<sup>Idea of getting a blog stolen from your local Stack Exchange nemesis, [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1712) ;)</sup>

Comment: You could have blog posts describing some golf-dedicated programming languages.

Comment: @Morwenn shush! Don't help the **enemy**! They shalt perish in dishonor, as they are [our nemesis](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14988630#14988630)

Comment: +1 just to get the battlefield into the blogosphere ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 Thou shalt not order me around for I am a free spirit.

Answer (score 5):

Without a more concrete vision of what the blog would cover, it's hard to see the benefit. That doesn't mean that it's necessarily a *bad* thing, but it does raise a risk that the contributors would lose interest quickly. It takes a lot of effort to write a blog post, so many blogs (including my [GolfScript blog](http://www.cheddarmonk.org/golfscriptblog/)) wind up abandoned with between 1 and 6 posts. On top of that, the integration between BlogOverflow and the main StackExchange sites is pretty weak, so you can't count on the main site driving traffic to the blog.

So I throw open a challenge to the upvoters: sell us all a vision for *how* the blog will benefit PCG.

Comment: That would be [phase 2](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/).

Comment: @Doorknob, I don't think so. Phase 2 is the negotiation of how to pull together the different visions that people have for the blog.

Comment: @Doorknob I agree with Peter here. I think the only reason those points are numbered are so they can refer to points 2 and 3 in the last one. I think "Raise the idea on meta" should naturally include the next two (at the *very* least #2). Without talking about the scope/purpose, how should I know whether I'm even interested?