# Code Golf Blog - Phase 2 - Define the Scope

Tags: discussion, blog-discussion

The general reaction on [phase 1 of the blog idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1446/3808) was "maybe, depending on what content we write there." So, let's figure that out!

From [the "official" blog guidelines](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) on this step:

> Is the blog about the site? Is it about the site’s topic? Is it about the industry around the topic? Keep in mind the audience of your community and their interests. Another generic blog about <x> may not be all that interesting.  A community blog should be interesting to both current members and potential new members.

So, what do you think we could blog about? Please note that this step **does not** mean that there will be a blog. We're just thinking of what we could write about if we had a blog here, and we could still decide that we don't want one at all.

Please submit one idea per answer, and vote on the ones you like and dislike!

<sup>Oh, and [Code Review stole our ad idea](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1781/36278) in return for us stealing their blog idea, so now we're even. ;)</sup>

Comment: I think the fact that I read your first and second posts about this makes it likely that I'll read the blog. Are *you* interested in writing for it?

Answer (score 8):

Here's one from the official blog post that I think will fit:

> **Highlight top content.** What great question was posted on the site recently?  Recognize it!  Don’t just copy the question and its answers to the blog, blog about the question and its answers.  A fine line there, eh?  Delve deeper into the question or an answer.  Add more context.  Compare or analyze answers against each other.  There is a lot to work with here.

This would be perfect for Code Golf. We could analyze some code that had been golfed really well, or we could provide commentary on a challenge or a solution.

Comment: Why don't you just blog on this post?

Comment: @TheDoctor Heh, infinite recursion! :P

Comment: We could diss code-trolling! :)

Answer (score 6):

We could blog about how new updates to languages (like the new Java 8) will affect Golfing in those languages, as well as compatibility with older answers.

With this it would help everyone to stay on the cutting edge of Code Golfing.

Answer (score 5):

How about blogging about code golf in general, not specifically related to our site? We could write posts about golfing languages, like GolfScript, or something related to golfing or programming challenges off-site that we think is interesting.

We could also post ideas about golfing or golfing languages, or review a topic related to PPCG.

Answer (score 4):

Another one from the official blog post:

> **Keep up with current events.** What is making news for your community?  What interests the community?

We could talk about new things happening in the Code Golf-verse, such as new tags (like [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) when it was first established) or new ideas.

Comment: check you spelling on this one  "thinks" -> "things"

Answer (score 2):

#### Another idea: language design and development

This is more relevant recently due to the surge in language creation. Sub-topics include:

- Posts by language creators about their languages; design, development, implementation, unique features, etc.
- Comparison of and/or expositions on language styles (stack-based/procedural/tacit, prefix/postfix/infix, etc.)
- In-depth explorations of the pros and cons of golfing languages vs. non-golfing languages (succinctness, readability, typing speed, execution speed, etc.)

I think this could be an especially rich field that PPCG members could contribute to due to the plethora of language creators *and* users of languages made by PPCGers.