# What should we write about on our blog?

Tags: discussion, blog-discussion

We're currently waiting on a solid consensus on [how to host a blog](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22005/66833), but while we wait, we should collect ideas for what blog posts should discuss. **Suggest your ideas here**.

Below, submit one topic per answer. Each answer should also contain the list of users (potentially just one) who are willing to write the blog post. The topic should be something they can write at least 1000 words, and should be related to the site in some obvious way. The topic description can be anything from 1 sentence to an entire draft of the blog post.

Users should suggest ways to improve the topic of the post, as well as suggesting other related content that could be included in the post. If users agree that a specific topic should be a blog post, upvote the proposal. If not, downvote.

Every 2 weeks, starting from a date to be decided, the top voted answer will be turned into the latest blog post, edited down to a link to the post and deleted.

Discussion about these topics can be done on the [CGCC Blog Chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123200/cgcc-blog-chat)

Answer (score 17):

## Under-appreciated / low-visibility high-quality answers

We could include a recurring section including some answers from the past period of time that have a lot of work put into them but haven't gotten the visibility or the upvotes they deserve.

Comment: Just to be clear, this won't be a blog post, just a section of it, right?

Comment: @user Yes. The idea is each post includes a little section with a few answers and maybe one or two lines highlighting them for visibility

Comment: This would be awesome, I love this idea.

Answer (score 16):

### Language design and development

This is more relevant recently due to the surge in language creation. Sub-topics include:

- Posts by language creators about their languages; design, development, implementation, unique features, etc.
- Comparison of and/or expositions on language styles (stack-based/procedural/tacit, prefix/postfix/infix, etc.)
- In-depth explorations of the pros and cons of golfing languages vs. non-golfing languages (succinctness, readability, typing speed, execution speed, etc.)

I think this could be an especially rich field that PPCG members could contribute to due to the plethora of language creators *and* users of languages made by PPCGers.

---

<sub>[a repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9089/90614)</sub>

---

#### Users who could write about this

- Wezl (knowledge about language design and development, but not much specifically about golfing/esolangs)
- Lyxal
- Redwolf Programs
- caird coinheringaahing
- hyper-neutrino (knows a bit about some of the low-level implementation details about language design)
- Seggan (built a JVM compiler for a Vyxal derivative)
- You! (add yourself here)

Comment: This is a good idea, but it will largely overlap with [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/198446/36398). It's probably better to keep all the information in the same question

Answer (score 12):

## Making your esolang tryable online without Dennis: creating esolang usability yourself

A post explaining how to make an online interpreter out of an already existing offline interpreter as getting languages added to TIO is currently an impractical solution.

### Writing candidates

- Lyxal
- Redwolf Programs
- Wasif
- add you

Comment: Might be better a section of a post about making your own language, rather than its own thing

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms the way I would write it would cover a more specific guide rather than a quick few ways of suggestions.

Comment: I can try, I guess?

Answer (score 11):

## How to write a good explanation

Perhaps a post could be made that gave advice on writing good explanations that are accessible even to users who don't know a language or algorithm particularly well.

#### Users who could write this:

- caird coinheringaahing
- hyper-neutrino
- DLosc
- Razetime
- *your name here!*

Answer (score 11):

## History of golfing languages

An outline of how we went from practical languages to somewhat readable programs in golfscript/pyth/cjam to Unicode gibberish winning every challenge.

### Users who could write

- Lyxal
- caird coinheringaahing
- add yourself here

Comment: I'd be happy to contribute to this as well I can, given that I spend far too much time browsing the forgotten transcripts of chat :)

Answer (score 11):

## Introduction to rarely used but interesting esolangs

This is meant to be a recurring topic, maybe once in a couple months. While LotM includes general-purpose languages and has an emphasis on general usability across challenges, this blog post will exclusively introduce esolangs and highlight certain aspects of it (along with a few specific challenges/answers).

### Languages and users to write about each language

- Flurry: Bubbler
- Labyrinth: Razetime
- Brain-Flak:
- (Hexagony?)
- (Stack Cats?)
- P'': 4D4850
- BitCycle: DLosc
- Forte: DLosc (*and/or someone else who knows the language better*)

Comment: I'd be willing to learn and talk about rarely used languages for the purpose of this if the user(s) who actively used them are no longer around / active.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino In that case, Brain-Flak might be a good candidate. As far as I'm aware, none of the heavy Brain-Flak users are active anymore, but we have plenty to talk about it (all the golfing tips, Brain-Flak-specific algorithms, and a >1000-byte answer).

Comment: Okay. I'll add myself to it - I've used Brain-Flak a couple of times before and I know approximately how it's used; I'll familiarize myself with some of the more complex parts of it.

Comment: I'm willing to write about labyrinth.

Comment: "None of the heavy Brain-Flak users are active anymore". :(  I would be happy to write about Brain-Flak, or alternatively lost.

Comment: I could probably blab on and on about 2D (or other dimensional) languages in general

Comment: @JoKing That would definitely make an interesting topic :)

Comment: I think I might have fun writing about turing machines or P'' (P double prime), which is derived from a turing machine, and Brainf**k is derived from P'' (The only difference being that BF has I/O). It might also be fun to write about Excel (yes, the spreadsheet program) which is turing complete, though I don't have nearly enough experience programming in Excel.

Comment: P'' explanation: https://esolangs.org/wiki/P%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2  Also, I might be the only user to have posted something in P''

Comment: Basically, it's BF but worse

Comment: I can try writing about Fishing?

Answer (score 10):

## How to get started learning a stack based golfing language

A post þat teaches þe basics of using any stack based language (stack mechanics, common operators and ways of control flow)

### Writing Candidates

- Lyxal
- Wezl
- Razetime
- add yourself here

Answer (score 9):

## How to write a KotH

Tips all about KotHs. How to do design them, how to write a good specification, how to make a controller, etc.

### Users who could write this:

- Redwolf Programs
- [others]

Answer (score 9):

## History of Code Golf and/or CGCC

As a slightly more general addition to hyper-neutrino's [suggestion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22082/79857), this could cover things like Code Golf on Stack Overflow, abandoned challenge types like [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded), the addition of things like "every language is its own sub-challenge", and so on. Could be a smaller section of every post, or its own standalone one.

### Users who could write this:

- Redwolf Programs
- caird coinheringaahing
- [others]

Answer (score 7):

## Are golfing languages good for the site?

<sup>[Accepted and written about in PPCG Blog #1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23551/cgcc-blog-1-are-golfing-languages-good-or-bad-for-the-site?cb=1) by Redwolf and caird.</sup>

Comment: I'd be happy to contribute to the "yes" side of the argument :)

Answer (score 7):

## How to make a golfing language

A more specific post than the other language development one, covering things like tacit vs. stack based, custom code pages, and so on. Could go with my other golfing language related suggestion, or not.

### People who could write this:

- Redwolf Programs
- Lyxal
- [others]

Answer (score 7):

## The pros and cons of challenge types other than [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The post would discuss both the advantages and disadvantages of writing challenges that use scoring criteria other than [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), for example [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers), [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) and more.

Some pros off the top of my head:

- They're often novel challenge ideas, more so than [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), and so people are more likely to upvote and remember them
- They can be a fun "distraction" or "break" in the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) monotony on the site

Some cons:

- They require more work to find a good and objective winning criteria
- They often require more effort and engagement to write and successfully pull off, especially on the author's part

### Writers

- caird coinheringaahing
- Redwolf Programs
- *add yourself*

Comment: I don't think these posts are community wiki, unless meta requires more rep to edit community wikis.

Comment: @4D4850 You can make a specific answer community wiki by clicking the "Community Wiki" checkbox in the bottom right of the editor

Comment: No, I made my answer community wiki, I just don't think the other answers are community wiki, because it just says that I can't suggest an edit because it' not tag wiki, and also because the answer boxes don't say community wiki above them.

Answer (score 6):

## Things new users should know

A post outlining information about the code golf site that new users might not necessarily know from the welcome posts (e.g. SBCS, TIO links, etc)

### Writing Candidates

- Lyxal
- add yourself here

Answer (score 4):

## TNB Highlights / TNB History

(Just a random idea. Maybe it's a really terrible one.)

We could include a section on each / some of the posts with some highlights from the past few weeks of chat. Not everything that's on the starboard, but specifically very funny (and still funny, not just in the moment) or very interesting discussions / messages (remember that you can bookmark a conversation and then link to it).

Alternatively, as a topic for one post, we could write about the history of TNB over the years (thanks to Lyxal for this suggestion).

Just throwing this idea out there.

Comment: I think it can be considered an option along with "underappreciated answer". A blog post may include one of them (or both, if the main article is slightly shorter than normal).

Comment: @Bubbler I think this is a great idea. Maybe if we have other suggestions for small additions that aren't real full topics, we could mix and match them depending on how long the topic content was for that post.

Comment: One thing I'd be concerned about this is the fact that a lot of the "highlights" of TNB are very related to the [memes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/the-many-memes-of-ppcg), especially anything from 2014-2017, which could tread dangerously close to ["an FAQ on how to be irritating"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13022/66833)

Comment: I agree with caird here: more preference should be given to interesting discussions than to funny ones (unless they're extremely humorous)

Answer (score 3):

## User spotlight

This could be a part of a bigger post. It would focus on a certain user each time and outline things like preferred golfing languages, best challenges, most iconic TNB quote etc.

### People to write about

- Redwolf (for being notable, outstanding at making KotHs)

### Writing Candidates

- Lyxal

Comment: I think a good first user to focus on would be Redwolf, as he is outstanding at making KotHs, and is a notable user all-round.

Answer (score 0):

## Preliminary opinions on the Blog

It would be about what people think about the new blog. Would have a section on in-depth opinions, as well as general reception. If and when done for real, would have a post made before it as an upvote/downvote poll, using upvotes and downvotes for voting.

Writers:
4D4850
*Add your name here, if you helped write*

Opinions:
4D4850: I think the blog is great, because it provides a community-based source of news. However, I'm a little worried it'll be a flop because I'm not sure many people would particularly care about what's happening on Meta.

*Add username and opinions here, using the opinion I wrote above as an example of formatting*

Comment: This feels like it should be a question for Meta (and we've already decided to go ahead with the blog anyway).

Comment: @user It's meant for reception of the blog after it's first 1 or 2 posts, to see how it's being received and what people think could be improved about the blog.

Comment: I see, that makes more sense.